# Conducting common-attribute dissolution ONLY on adjacent features using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes, dissolve

I am working in QGIS. I have a shapefile of city parcels, which I am trying to dissolve where parcels have matching owners AND are touching. "Owner" is an attribute field.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The Dissolve processing algorithm takes an optional Attribute parameter. I'm thinking some workflow where you would Dissolve the whole parcels layer by Owner. Then split the dissolved multiparts to single parts. When a person owns only one property the generated object should be the same after each step. If a person owns three properties, two of which are touching, then after the Dissolve there will be one object comprising two parts - one for the adjacent parcels and one for the other parcel. Then after the multiparts to single you end up with two objects.

Comment: @MBain this appears to have worked perfectly. Thank you very much. I am learning as I go, so this is much appreciated.